# How to make visual studio highlight buggy code files like netbeans?

Tags: visual-studio, netbeans, add-in

After moving to c# (from java) and using Visual Studio, I found that visual studio does not have the Netbeans' feature that highlight the buggy code files in files browser and lines that contains errors in the left side of the code. I think this feature very useful and let me find some error before press compile/run. so I want to know if there is a add-in for visual studio to enable this feature.

**Edit :**
I don't mean underline the error ! , but insert some error icon at line start and on the file icon in files browser (the big benefit of this feature when we have too many code files or too many line in a file)

Comment: Well, it does.  I don't get the problem, Build + Build gives you a list too.  It won't slap you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this features need two addin to be enabled :

1. highlight buggy code files (tab) use : [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)
2. highlight buggy lines in a code file use :  [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)   (thanks to [Ilya Ryzhenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719222/how-to-make-visual-studio-highlight-buggy-code-files-like-netbeans/3724541#3724541))

Answer (score 1):

What version of Visual Studio do you have? VS 2010 has this feature enabled by default.

Comment: i am using vs 2010 but it doesnt have this feature

Comment: VS2010 highlights the lines, but not the files

Comment: Check Tools | Options > Text Editor | C# | Advanced, under Editor Help

Comment: The option is located under Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Editor Help. It probably got disabled somehow, try re-enabling it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), which has code analyses including Solution Wide.